# How can I get Alexa to send authentication to android app before executing voice command

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

So this is what I am trying to do.  When I ask Alexa do turn on light (for example) it then needs to send an authentication code to an android app (which I need to develop as well) then when the users confirms the code then the light needs to turn on.

Can this be done and is there any tutorials which will explain this or is there a better way of securing voice commands to perform certain functions?

Any help will be appreciated.

I followed [this](https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/develop-your-own-raspberry-pi-alexa-skill-and-control-pi-remotely/) tutorial so am think of when asking to turn on light, Alexa the ask's for pin or password and then send the command to the GPIO Pin

Below is the code on the tutorial:

```
import logging
import os

from flask import Flask
from flask_ask import Ask, request, session, question, statement
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

app = Flask(__name__)
ask = Ask(app, "/")
logging.getLogger('flask_ask').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

STATUSON = ["on", "switch on", "enable", "power on", "activate", "turn 
on"] 
# all values that are defined as synonyms in type
STATUSOFF = ["off", "switch off", "disactivate", "turn off", "disable", 
"turn off"]

@ask.launch
def launch():
speech_text = 'Welcome to the Raspberry Pi alexa automation.'
return 
question(speech_text).reprompt(speech_text).simple_card(speech_text)

@ask.intent('LightIntent', mapping = {'status':'status'})
# HERE TO ASK FOR CODE THEN IF CORRECT CONTINUE TO TURN LIGHT ON
def Gpio_Intent(status,room):
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.OUT)
if status in STATUSON:
    GPIO.output(17,GPIO.HIGH)
    return statement('Light was turned on')
elif status in STATUSOFF:
    GPIO.output(17,GPIO.LOW)
    return statement('Light was turned off')
else:
    return statement('Sorry, this command is not possible.')

@ask.intent('AMAZON.HelpIntent')
def help():
speech_text = 'You can say hello to me!'
return  
question(speech_text).reprompt(speech_text).simple_card('HelloWorld', 
speech_text)


@ask.session_ended
def session_ended():
return "{}", 200


if __name__ == '__main__':
if 'ASK_VERIFY_REQUESTS' in os.environ:
    verify = str(os.environ.get('ASK_VERIFY_REQUESTS', '')).lower()
    if verify == 'false':
        app.config['ASK_VERIFY_REQUESTS'] = False
app.run(debug=True)
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you pair your app with alexa?

Comment: Well that's the thing, can it be done?  I mean if you want to secure lets say to restrict access to turn on a specific light in your house and only by approving the code sent to your app (which somehow needs to be linked to Alexa either by cell phone number or something)

Comment: If you use Bluetooth I wouldn't use a 2nd password. https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=GG8S76D3BYTGC424

Comment: Where will it send it if doesn't know whos asking?

Comment: "Or maybe I can say turn on light and Alexa will ask for password then if correct proceed to turn on light?" - Alexa has a fairly short timeout on responses. Would the skill be able to send the password to the phone and have the customer read the response in 10-20 seconds? How are you linking the app to the skill, so the handlers are sending the password to the correct phone for the customer?